# How I can tell if a right is being removed by a remote Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, scm

I need to know how I can tell if a right is being removed by a Group Policy.  The right in question is [`SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981.aspx) and is preventing code from opening the Service Control Manager on a remote machine. The application with administrator level privileges on the local computer under a domain level account that has admin privileges on the target server. Both machines are running Window Server 2008 R2 and both firewalls are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have administrative rights on the remote machine, you can use `gpresult.exe` to generate a full report of all policies applied to the system and/or to a given user.

```
gpresult.ext /S <SERVER> /USER <DOMAIN>\<USER> /H <FILENAME>.html
```

Will create an HTML report detailing all policies applied to the remote system and to the specified user account whenever it logs on to that system. You can also of course run the command on the system itself, after logging on with your preferred user account; if doing this, then the `/S` and `/USER` parameters can be omitted.

Comment: This only lists the policies, not the rights within the policies. Is there a way to list the rights within the group policies, that are being allowed or denied?

Comment: For each policy are listed all the applied settings; if you don't find anything about rights there, then no policy is setting them.